# Algorithm to group people by two factors

Tags: algorithm

I have thought long about this but couldn't figure it out. I am looking for an algorithm ( in any language) to group a bunch of people by the following these 2 rules:

1. Group by ascending skill level which is represented by a number (the higher the more skilled).  The best and weakest in the group should not differ by more than 1 point, where possible.
2. Spread out people from the same country as far as possible, i.e. dont put people from the same country in the same group, while at the same time not breaking rule 1 above. A group should not consist of people from 1 country where possible.

Each group can have at most 4 person (where possible) or 3 persons e.g. if there are 18 people, then they are split into 3 groups of 4 and 2 groups of 3.

Sample data (Skill level followed by country) :

- 5 US
- 5 US
- 5 US
- 5 US
- 6 GB
- 6 GB
- 6 GB
- 7 CN
- 7 CN
- 7 CN
- 7 CN
- 7 HK
- 8 US
- 8 US
- 8 US
- 8 CA
- 8 CN
- 8 CN

..to be grouped into 2groups of 4s and 2groups of 3s

Please help if you have any idea?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following.

First, aggregate the data by country and skill level, so the data looks more like:

```
US    5    4
GB    6    3
. . .
```

Sort this by the highest ranking first.

Then use a greedy algorithm.

- Determine the number of members in the group (either size or size - 1)
- Take one from the first group (highest ranking).
- Continue taking one from each subsequent group meeting the country condition (so you might need to skip the US).

That defines the first group.

Then repeat.

This is not guaranteed to be optimal.  But then again, optimality is not defined for the problem.  Which is more important?  Country diversity or skill sameness?

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the suggestion. The skill level can differ by at most one point while at the same time we want to avoid putting people from 1 country into one single group (so you have diversity of country). How do you determine the ranking ?